# How do you get a new instance from InjectionToken

Tags: angular

I created a configurable module which accepts a LOGGER_TOKEN for type LoggerInterface.

By default, LOGGER_TOKEN is set to LoggerA class.

```
export const LOGGER_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<LoggerInterface>('LOGGER_TOKEN');

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ShoppingCartComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [ShoppingCartComponent]

})
export class ShoppingCartModule {
  static forRoot(options?: any): ModuleWithProviders<any> {
    return {
      ngModule: ShoppingCartModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: LOGGER_TOKEN,
          useClass: options?.logger ? options.logger : LoggerA
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

In a component, how do you create a new instance of this LOGGER_TOKEN?
I am using Angular 9. Thanks.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-shopping-cart',
  templateUrl: './shopping-cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shopping-cart.component.scss'],
  providers: [ {provide: LoggerInterface, useClass: LOGGER_TOKEN } ] //  DOES NOT WORK ************ **************
})
export class ShoppingCartComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(@Inject(LOGGER_TOKEN) logger: LoggerInterface) {
    logger.log();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Playground:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gnt8mz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshopping-cart%2Fshopping-cart%2Fshopping-cart.component.ts

Comment: Do you mean a different instance in the same module..?

Comment: Yes. If I set provider as [{provide:LoggerA, useClass:LoggerA}], each component instance will be injected a new LoggerA instance. But I am no idea how to create instance from a injection token. Thanks.

Comment: I'm surprised the component level provider doesn't work..? That should work as long as you do not also provide it on module level I guess?

Comment: I added a playground, you may try it. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gnt8mz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshopping-cart%2Fshopping-cart%2Fshopping-cart.component.ts